# Add axes all around the plot in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, border

I have a figure and I have ploted some value. My issue is that I cannot seem to be able to specify that the figure should have axis on all sides.

My figure:

[image]

I would like to have the borders like in the figure below. Meaning all around the plot there are axes:

[image]

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}
\begin{filecontents}{data_ape_dist.dat}
x,y,y2
0,0,0
0.05,2.021,1.781
0.1,1.928,1.734
0.15,1.798,1.634
0.2,1.567,1.45
0.25,1.316,1.274
0.3,1.167,1.177
0.35,0.948,0.993
0.4,0.744,0.869
0.45,0.652,0.718
0.5,0.492,0.57
0.55,0.428,0.465
0.6,0.304,0.389
0.65,0.256,0.272
0.7,0.203,0.229
0.75,0.133,0.178
0.8,0.092,0.141
0.85,0.058,0.091
0.9,0.035,0.063
0.95,0.036,0.051
1,0.021,0.043
1.05,0.012,0.026
1.1,0.014,0.031
1.15,0.011,0.018
1.2,0.01,0.012
1.25,0.012,0.022
1.3,0.012,0.012
1.35,0.006,0.006
1.4,0.013,0.005
1.45,0.009,0.008
1.5,0.003,0.006
1.55,0.004,0.007
1.6,0.001,0.009
1.65,0.001,0.002
1.7,0.002,0.003
1.75,0,0.003
1.8,0.001,0.005
1.85,0.001,0.002
1.9,0,0.002
1.95,0,0
2,0.002,0.002
2.05,0.002,0.002
2.1,0,0.002
2.15,0,0.001
2.2,0,0.001
2.25,0,0.003
2.3,0,0
2.35,0,0
2.4,0,0
2.45,0,0.001
2.5,0,0.001
2.55,0,0.001
\end{filecontents}


\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}


    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines*=left,
        axis background/.style={fill=gray!10},
        width=12cm,
        height=8cm,
        x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
        y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.05,.5)},anchor=south},
        ylabel= Density,
        xlabel= Absolute percentage errors for SBP and GICS,
        axis on top,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=2,
        ymin=-0.017,
        ymax=2.5,
        domain=xmin:xmax
    ]
        \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:xmin,0) -- (axis cs:xmax,0);
        \addplot[name path=table, fill=MyBlue!45, opacity=0.7] table [ x index=0, y index=1, col sep=comma, ] {data_ape_dist.dat};
        \addplot[name path=table, fill=red!45, opacity=0.6] table [ x index=0, y index=2, col sep=comma, ] {data_ape_dist.dat};
        fill between [of=axis and table];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

I have tried to plot background rectangle, or specify `[frame background rectangle]` after `\begin{tikzpicture}`, but did not work. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: Remove the axis lines= left line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were numerous problems with your code, which did not compile.  The code below compiles and produces what you asked for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}
\begin{filecontents}{data_ape_dist.dat}
x,y,y2
0,0,0
0.05,2.021,1.781
0.1,1.928,1.734
0.15,1.798,1.634
0.2,1.567,1.45
0.25,1.316,1.274
0.3,1.167,1.177
0.35,0.948,0.993
0.4,0.744,0.869
0.45,0.652,0.718
0.5,0.492,0.57
0.55,0.428,0.465
0.6,0.304,0.389
0.65,0.256,0.272
0.7,0.203,0.229
0.75,0.133,0.178
0.8,0.092,0.141
0.85,0.058,0.091
0.9,0.035,0.063
0.95,0.036,0.051
1,0.021,0.043
1.05,0.012,0.026
1.1,0.014,0.031
1.15,0.011,0.018
1.2,0.01,0.012
1.25,0.012,0.022
1.3,0.012,0.012
1.35,0.006,0.006
1.4,0.013,0.005
1.45,0.009,0.008
1.5,0.003,0.006
1.55,0.004,0.007
1.6,0.001,0.009
1.65,0.001,0.002
1.7,0.002,0.003
1.75,0,0.003
1.8,0.001,0.005
1.85,0.001,0.002
1.9,0,0.002
1.95,0,0
2,0.002,0.002
2.05,0.002,0.002
2.1,0,0.002
2.15,0,0.001
2.2,0,0.001
2.25,0,0.003
2.3,0,0
2.35,0,0
2.4,0,0
2.45,0,0.001
2.5,0,0.001
2.55,0,0.001
\end{filecontents}


\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}


    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
    \begin{axis}[
    %    axis lines*=left,
        axis background/.style={fill=gray!10},
        width=12cm,
        height=8cm,
        x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
        y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.05,.5)},anchor=south},
        ylabel= Density,
        xlabel= Absolute percentage errors for SBP and GICS,
        axis on top,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=2,
        ymin=-0.017,
        ymax=2.5,
        domain=0:2
    ]
        \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:2,0);
        \addplot[name path=table, fill=blue!45, opacity=0.7] table [ x index=0, y index=1, col sep=comma, ] {data_ape_dist.dat};
        \addplot[name path=table, fill=red!45, opacity=0.6] table [ x index=0, y index=2, col sep=comma, ] {data_ape_dist.dat};
        fill between [of=axis and table];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir!